# Django: How to create a signal for deleting a instance of pre_save signal?

Tags: django, django-signals

I have the following pre_save signal in my models:

```
@receiver(pre_save, sender=Purchase)
def user_created_purchase_cgst(sender,instance,*args,**kwargs):
    c = Journal.objects.filter(user=instance.user, company=instance.company).count() + 1
    if instance.cgst_alltotal != None and instance.cgst_alltotal != 0:
        Journal.objects.update_or_create(
            user=instance.user,
            company=instance.company,
            by=ledger1.objects.filter(user=instance.user,company=instance.company,name__icontains='CGST').first(),
            to=instance.party_ac,
            defaults={
                'counter' : c,
                'date': instance.date,
                'voucher_id' : instance.id,
                'voucher_type' : "Journal",
                'debit': instance.cgst_alltotal,
                'credit': instance.cgst_alltotal}
            )
```

I want to create another signal similar to the above that when the sender is deleted then the sender instance will also get deleted.

i.e when a `Purchase` object is deleted then the corresponding `Journal` object which is created by the pre_save signal will get deleted.

Any idea anyone how to perform this?

Thank you

Comment: Your question is confusing. There is nothing being deleted on your code. What exactly are you trying to do.

Comment: Just read my question I said I want to create another signal for deleting the instance whenever the sender is being deleted

Comment: Why don't you just use django's `pre_delete` or `post_delete` built-in signals? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/signals/#pre-delete

Comment: I am actually new to django and have not used much of `pre_delete` signal...So I was wondering how it should be done

Comment: I'll compose a proper answer for you.

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will be something like this:

```
@receiver(pre_delete, sender=Purchase)
def delete_related_journal(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    journal = instance.journal # instance is your Purchase instance that is
    # about to be deleted
    journal.delete()
```

But be aware, if the Journal purchase Foreign Key is setted to `on_delete=models.CASCADE`, you don't have to do this at all. So, if CASCADE is not setted, you might want to do it instead using a signal.

```
class JournalModel(models.Model):
    # Your other fields here
    purchase = models.ForeignKey(Purchase, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

More on `pre_delete` signals: [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/signals/#pre-delete)

Comment: `from django.db.models.signals import pre_delete
from django.dispatch import receiver` are the imports required